# ¿Cómo hacer un SELECT por fecha en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un programa con PHP, SQL y MySQL que tiene que seleccionar de una tabla `pedidos_remoto` un conjunto de pedidos, que se hayan hecho a una determinada agencia y un determinado día. Tengo dos problemas:

a) No soy capaz de seleccionar los pedidos que se han hecho en una determinada fecha. El campo `fecha` de la tabla en MySQL ahora mismo tiene información de este estilo: `2020-10-19 16:50:07` de modo que me es imposible hacer un SELECT que me dé todos los pedidos de, por ejemplo, el 19/10/2020 porque al aparecerme en el campo también la hora/minutos/segundos, no me devuelve ningún registro.

b) Por otro lado, ¿se pueden combinar un WHERE + OR + AND? Es decir, la consulta final que yo quiero hacer es algo de este estilo:

```
SELECT * FROM `pedidos_remoto` WHERE `agencia`='AGENCIA Y' OR `agencia`='AGENCIA X' AND `fecha`=19-10-2020
```

Sin embargo, aunque no me da error, sé que está mal, porque me está devolviendo sólo el nº de registros que aparecerían si yo hiciera:

```
SELECT * FROM `pedidos_remoto` WHERE `agencia`='AGENCIA Y'
```

Es decir, es como que lee hasta el OR y ya ahí se para. Por tanto, ¿cómo podría hacer esa consulta? Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Si puedes combinar operadores lógicos pero debes darle jerarquía de operación con los paréntesis, además puedes usar la función date para para poder seleccionar las fechas sin considerar las horas, un ejemplo sería: WHERE (`agencia`='AGENCIA Y' OR `agencia`='AGENCIA X') AND DATE(`fecha`)='19-10-2020'

Comment: Ya me funciona. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Intentaste hacer la consulta usando funciones de fecha y hora?
aqui te las dejo:
https://documentation.help/MySQL-5.0-es/ch12s05.html

Answer (score 2):

Lo más sencillo para obtener las entradas de un día en específico ( uso la fecha que has puesto como ejemplo ) sería:

```
SELECT * FROM `pedidos_remoto` WHERE `fecha` > '2020-10-19 00:00:00' AND `fecha` < '2020-10-20 00:00:00'
```

En cuanto a el tema del WHERE OR AND, podrias probar a aislar las distintas condiciones entre parentesis:

```
SELECT * FROM `pedidos_remoto` WHERE (`agencia`='AGENCIA Y' OR `agencia`='AGENCIA X') AND  `fecha` > '2020-10-19 00:00:00 AND `fecha` < '2020-10-20 00:00:00'
```